Can many-worlds be testable, if considered in the context of reality as we know it?
This question concerns Hugh Everett's many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.
If we consider many-worlds within the context of the conscious beings that already exist in this world, then initial conditions at the origins of this universe could give rise to a many-worlds interpretation.
The fact that the unknowable contents of another observer's consciousness are unknowable should point to at least a better understanding in the way which consciousness has branched throughout time.
For example, if we cannot appeal to branched universes, can we appeal to the worlds of our fellow humans in this reality?
My question is: If many-worlds is not falsifiable in the original context, could it then be testable in the context of the huge number of conscious entities that already exist in this reality?
But it may be better posed as: Is the number of branched realities, pertaining to a single conscious observer, equal to the number of physical realities, pertaining to the physical realities of all physical observers... (a) since time began? (b) beginning at another significant origin?

"...in the context of the insanely huge number of conscious entities..." What does this mean? How is it relevant?

Why is "said" in quotes?

@hft the conscious entities on this planet include everything from humans to bats to insects etc, and my question is asking if this coheres with the number of possible universes in the original context of many-worlds.

@hft I think I left "said" in quotes to represent all parties, whom may be a part of either camp whether other conscious entities really exist or not.

This is not a physics question.

@hft... why not?

In physics we deal with one universe and we concern ourselves with elucidating the facts of that universe.

@hft It is possible to formulate the "many worlds" interpretation so that there is only ever one universe - see the answer below. You may not personally like the "many worlds" interpretation, but this is definitely a physics question.

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

This is not a "perfectly clear" question.

A paper on experimental testing of the Everett interpretation https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048

The answer given below is wrong. An answer to a relevantly similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/790258/how-can-the-copenhagen-and-everett-interpretations-of-quantum-mechanics-make-the/790389#790389

I think this question is kinda marginal cuz of the kooky stuff about consciousness, none of which can be blamed on the MWI since all the consciousness quantum theory collapse nonsense came from the Copenhagen camp.

The question author should read "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch for more on the MWI.

Please don't make drastic edits after the question has been answered and accepted.

Short answer: NO.

@DanielFBest I have already told you. Please stop making superfluous edits to this question. No amount of rewording will make it on-topic. If you are still blocked from asking new questions, just wait for 6 months and you will be able to ask one more.

@DanielFBest Also, instead of editing this question repeatedly, please instead consider fixing some of your deleted unanswered questions.

@VincentThacker the disclaimer says "needs details or clarity", not "this question is off topic". Also, there's no way of accessing deleted unanswered questions.

@DanielFBest You can access your deleted questions. Just go to the "Questions" tab of your profile. At the bottom there is a button to view deleted questions.

@hft Who says (besides yourself obviously) that physics is limited to one universe.. The \many Worlds interpretation is (unfortunately) a mainstream theory and a survey of physicists indicated a majority considered it their favourite interpretation of QM. (Which is a poor reflection on the discipline IMHO).


I think that the idea that our personal experience "branches" at every moment to produce multiple universes in which alternate selves exist is perhaps a stretch, i.e. beyond the realms of testable physics, firstly.

That isn't what the Everett interpretation says. It says that when a quantum system in a superposition of mutually-orthogonal states interacts with (is observed by) a quantum observer, the observer enters a superposition of mutually-orthogonal states correlated with the original system. Because they are mutually orthogonal, they do not interact, and cannot see one another. The observer is a superposition of observer states, each seeing exactly one outcome, each one apparently randomly selected. To the observer, it is as if each possible outcome of the quantum experiment happened in a separate world. But no universes are actually created, or 'split'. There is only one universe. No additional universe-splitting mechanisms or 'new physics' are introduced. It is simply the standard unitary evolution of wavefunctions from standard quantum physics, that predicts observers in a quantum universe will see exactly what we do see. There is no need for wavefunctions to collapse to explain why we see only one outcome. Mutual invisibility of orthogonal sub-states already explains it.
Proponents like it because of its elegance and simplicity, because it has much nicer properties like being linear, deterministic, local, causal, realist, etc., and because it constitutes a more detailed and comprehensive explanation of things. But because it makes exactly the same predictions about what is observed in Copenhagen collapse, the difference is not testable. The differences all occur in the part of the universe that Everett says we can never see; that Copenhagen says vanishes.

So, if many worlds is not falsifiable in the original context, could it at least approach falsifiability in the context of the insanely huge number of conscious entities that are "said" to exist in this reality?

Not for this reason. 'Insanity' implies conclusions drawn from invalid or disordered reasoning - and the number of conscious entities is a straightforward logical consequence/implication of the axioms of quantum physics excluding those describing wavefunction collapse. What's insane is rejecting the consequences of valid reasoning purely because the result is unfamiliar, unintuitive, or has emotionally undesired implications. It's no more 'insane', merely for being a very big number than the number of atoms in everyday objects, or the number of possible states of all the air molecules in a room.
Since there can never be any experimental evidence distinguishing them, you are free to accept or reject either on aesthetic or utilitarian grounds. It's far easier to do calculations assuming collapse. The picture of the state of the universe at any given moment it evokes is far easier to imagine, and far closer to our classical physics view. But collapse propagates faster than light, backwards-in-time, by an undefined, unmeasurable, unobservable, and really hard-to-imagine or understand mechanism. Neither interpretation is at all comfortable to our classically-trained intuitions.
However, both Copenhagen and Everett are still falsifiable in that they both make the same predictions about observations, that could yet turn out to be untrue. They would both be falsified simultaneously by such evidence that our current understanding of quantum physics was wrong. And given the well-known problems integrating quantum physics with general relativity, it wouldn't even be very surprising.

Upvoted for this:  "What's insane is rejecting the consequences of valid reasoning purely because the result is unfamiliar, unintuitive, or has emotionally undesired implications."

By this definition Niels Bohr and his collaborators are insane as they completely rejected the theory.[ (Wheeler too.)
